# How to add a license file to BOOT-INF\lib in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

We have a spring boot(version 2.3.12) project built using maven. We are using a third-party application that requires a license file(abc.lic) to be present in the lib folder. How do we add the license file as part of BOOT-INF\lib folder?

Comment: Does it require the file really in the lib folder or rather just in the classpath?

Comment: The documentation says the file should be present in the lib folder. I tried adding it to the resources folder which didn't help.